# Constructive Burnside's lemma

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

[Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) is a clever tool to calculate the number of distinct configurations up to a given symmetry group.

[Wikipedia's example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma#Example_application) shows that the number of rotationally distinct colourings of the faces of a cube using three colours is 57. [This introduction](https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/Huisinga.pdf) similarly shows that there are 6 distinct squares whose vertices have one of two colours.

But what if we actually want to *construct* the 57 distinct-coloured cubes, or the 6 distinct-coloured squares, instead of just counting them? Is there a non-brute-force way of doing this?

Comment: It's unclear to me what it would mean to give a non-brute-force method of constructing a bunch of objects. The difference between constructing $n$ objects and computing $n$ is that you can write down $n$ using $\log n$ bits, but writing down $n$ objects presumably takes at least $n$ bits. Here $n$ might be e.g. the number of isomorphism classes of graphs on $10$ vertices, which you can count using Burnside's lemma and which is something like $\frac{1}{10!} 2^{{10 \choose 2}}$, which is pretty big.